# curl(6) could not resolve host:mutlipart- Authentication required

Tags: curl, multipartform-data, form-data

API is working fine in postman; I took curl command from postman code snippet but its not working in command prompt

curl -k -L -v https://doculink.qa.test123.com/otcs/llisapi.dll/api/v1/nodes -h otcsticket:EN27dfgtnokajsdaskdaskdjjklhfiuewdcbmsdnndsk -H Content-Type:mutlipart/form-data;boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary -F body={"type":144,"parent_id":741774,"name":"3postmancreation1.txt"} -F file=@c:/User/fileUpload.csv

Please help me where is the issue in this command

How to fix this issue

Answer (score 0):

"Not working" is too vague.
A link to the API documentation is required.

This is likely a little better.  I executed it in a Win 10 CMD prompt.
Without documentation, not much more I can do.

```
curl -k -L -v "https://doculink.qa.test123.com/otcs/llisapi.dll/api/v1/nodes" -H 'otcsticket:EN27dfgtnokajsdaskdaskdjjklhfiuewdcbmsdnndsk'  -F file=@c:/User/fileUpload.csv  -H 'Content-Type:mutlipart/form-data;boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary' -F body={"type":144,"parent_id":741774,"name":"3postmancreation1.txt"}
```

The way I troubleshoot command line curl is to convert it to curl in PHP.  It did not convert originally until I added some quotes. Capitalized -h to -H
The above curl translates with no error and executes at the command line (with error).

I used [LINK to curl converter](https://curlconverter.com/php/)

[image]